# Python: Parse thorn delimited file - code works on Windows, but not on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, amazon-ec2, character-encoding

The following code works fine in windows 7:

```
[30]  delim = b'\xc3\xbe'.decode() # 'þ'
[31]  reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter=delim)
```

However it fails on Amazon Linux on my ec2 instance using python 3.4, throwing the error:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file
>   data_loader.py on line 30, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

I am running it from the linux shell, ie:

```
python3 data_loader.py
```

However, when I use the Python 3.4 command line on the ec2 linux server, I get the expected:

```
>>> b'\xc3\xbe'.decode()
'þ'
```

I have tried setting delim to many things, including:

```
delim = '\xfe'
```

but I get the same error.

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on? Like I said, the code works fine on Python 3.4, windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the error caused by the comment since you haven't specified an encoding for the source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by including a non-ascii character in the comment on line 30.

According to the [PEP article](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) that python itself links you to:

> This PEP proposes to introduce a syntax to declare the encoding of
>       a Python source file. The encoding information is then used by the
>       Python parser to interpret the file using the given encoding. Most
>       notably this enhances the interpretation of Unicode literals in
>       the source code and makes it possible to write Unicode literals
>       using e.g. UTF-8 directly in an Unicode aware editor.

...

> Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other
>       encoding hints are given.

To fix your error, you can either remove the comment from line 30, or you can specify a file encoding that the python interpreter will use to read that comment correctly.

For example, if you used the latin-1 encoding when creating your source file to add the `'þ'` character, then add this line to the top of your python script:

```
# coding=latin-1
```

Replace the encoding with whatever the file's actual encoding is and you should be good to go.